# API or JavaScript inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, sql, django, fetch-api

I have a JS function in my template which works with fetch commands to relay to a Django view. The strange part is that it as expected most of the time but sometimes it just doesn't and I cannot figure out why.

JS in template:

```
<script>
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link")[1].innerHTML != "Log In") {
        var like = document.querySelector(".likes");
        var quantity = document.querySelector(".quantity");
        like.addEventListener("click", () => likes())
        function likes () {
            fetch(`/likes/${like.value}`, {
                method: "PUT"});
            if (like.innerHTML.slice(0, 2) != "Un") {
                like.innerHTML = "Unlike &#128148";
            }
            else {
                like.innerHTML = "Like &#10084";
            }
            fetch(`/likes/${like.value}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(post => {
                console.log(post["liked"]);
                quantity.innerHTML = post["liked"].length;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def likes(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "No such post"}, status=404)
    
    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(post.serialize())

    if request.method == "PUT":
        #data = json.loads(request)
        if user not in post.liked.all() and post.poster != user:
            print("adding")
            post.liked.add(user)
            post.save()
        else:
            print("removing")
            post.liked.remove(user)
            post.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

It should be alternating between an empty list and a list which contains a two.

[image: janky JS]

However you can see that, although it usually works right, it has a spot where there are several "[2]" in a row and sometimes it has several "[]" in a row too.

Actually this only started after adding the second fetch but I can't understand why; before then it alternated without problems.

Comment: I didn't dig in to your code very deeply, but `fetch` is async, since you don't `await` it there is no guarantee that your post is received before your get runs.

Comment: I think you can use `await`
 to wait for the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jared Smith
said in comments there is no guarantee order of `fetch` as it is asynchronous, to control the order use `async` and `await` to wait for the result of response something like this:

```
    like.addEventListener("click", async () => await likes())
    async function likes () {
        await fetch(`/likes/${like.value}`, {
            method: "PUT"});
        if (like.innerHTML.slice(0, 2) != "Un") {
            like.innerHTML = "Unlike &#128148";
        }
        else {
            like.innerHTML = "Like &#10084";
        }
        await fetch(`/likes/${like.value}`);
        const post = await response.json();
        quantity.innerHTML = post["liked"].length;
    }
```