# How to ensure fetch GET request runs after database updated?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, django

I am having trouble ensuring that my GET request in Javascript runs after my PUT.

Sometimes the JSON promise returns with updated data sometimes it does not!

It appears to be random. It always displays correctly upon page reload.

I am getting a "Fetch failed loading: PUT" error in my console despite the database being updated successfully.

I know of await/async but was unclear if this was my solution and if so how I would implement with the correct syntax.

Here is my JS:

```
function like(id) {

    like_button = document.getElementById(`like-button-${id}`);
    
    if (like_button.style.backgroundColor == 'white') {
        fetch(`/like/${id}`, {
            method:'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                like: true
            })
        });

        like_button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    else {
        fetch(`/like/${id}`, {
            method:'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                like: false
            })
        });

        like_button.style.backgroundColor = 'white';


    }

    fetch(`/like/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(post => {
        like_button.innerHTML = post.likes;
    });

}
```

In case it is helpful here is my view in views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def like(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(post.serialize(), safe=False)

    if request.method == "PUT":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(data.get("like"))
        if data.get("like"):
            post.Likes.add(user)
        else:
            post.Likes.remove(user)
        post.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

[Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILLfH.png)

Comment: what do you get as error in console logs? also, do you need to fire the 2nd API after the 1st one's completion? If so, then you need to keep it in an `await` state or write the rest of your logic in the `then` section

Comment: I just added a link to the error message at the bottom of the post - The fetch at the bottom of my js function is supposed to retrieve the data that has just been updated by PUT requests in my if/else statement. So I believe the answer to your question is yes? Are you saying I need to put the former or the latter in an await state?

Comment: yup, that should fix it, but it seems that your PUT request is failing, having a look at your code, everything lgtm so might need to dig into the server side to see if there is anything wrong there

Comment: That is because fetch by default is asynchronous in nature so it won't wait for other request this is already answered here check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70569698/api-or-javascript-inconsistencies/70569925#70569925

Comment: Made it an async function with await before every fetch...everything works now.  Not sure whats going on with my PUT request maybe has something to do with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477805/why-do-i-get-fetch-failed-loading-when-it-actually-worked